# MVVMCross binding in Android not work

Tags: android, mvvm, mvvmcross

I am new at MVVMCross, I rewrite the demo code in [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-00-FirstDemo) : , not changed to much, but the binding thing is not work, it should show error logs for debugging. I also read the naming convention
Here is my viewmodel class

```
 public class FirstViewModel:MvxViewModel
{
    private string _firstName;
    private string _lastName;

    public string FirstName {
        set { SetProperty(ref _firstName, value); RaisePropertyChanged(() => FirstName); }
        get { return _firstName; }
    }

    public string LastName {
        set { SetProperty(ref _lastName, value); RaisePropertyChanged(() => LastName); }
        get { return _lastName; }
    }

    public string FullName {
        get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", _firstName, _lastName); }
    } 
}
```

View:

```
public class FirstView : MvxActivity<FirstViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.FirstView);
    }
}



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text FirstName" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text LastName" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    local:MvxBind="Text FullName" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change these line of code and it works:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => FullName
RaisePropertyChanged(() => FullName
```